# Facebook Error 191 and Subdomains

Tags: facebook, subdomain

I have an application that I want to have Facebook Authentication setup on. The application is using a loose MVC framework and thus the handling for the Facebook Authentication (the redirect) needs to be done via a module. Since this is under development I'm working off a development URL, which is a sub domain.

I've created an app, put it in sandbox mode, and set the App domain to "example.com" and the Site URL to "http://dev-site.example.com". My login URL is generated via the current Facebook PhP API and the redirect_uri is /facebookauth/processResponse. I click the link and get....

An error occurred with FTR_Sandbox. Please try again later.

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.

I'm at a loss here, I've tried a lot of different settings (Add Domain including the sub domain, with training slashes, without training slashes) and I keep getting that error.

What am I doing wrong!?

Comment: Ok. I got it. Boy I feel stupid.

The Facebook PhP object wants an associative array passed into its getLoginUrl method. Part of this array is the "redirect_ur**i**". I had redirect_url. Made that change, quick refresh, validated the link being printed, click and I see a authorization dialog from Facebook. 

YAY!

Comment: If your app url is http://sub-domain.domain.com, Then add **sub-domain.domain.com** as your domain

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you found a solution for your question, you can answer it your self and select it as the correct one, to flag this question as an answered one and help other users with the same error.

Answer (score 1):

If your app url is sub-domain.domain.com, Then add sub-domain.domain.com as your domain